# Expo push notification with image content

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-publish

I want to Send Expo Notification with image content like this, but in Expo documentation nothing is mentioned how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This feature isn't supported in expo yet. You have to eject your project and go throw bad reactnative experience, and link with firebase npm or onesignal.

Comment: what is  **bad reactnat** ??

Comment: bad reactnative experience. and link with fierbase npm or onesignal.

Comment: try sdk 40. befor ejecting